# How to create directory in an Android project that will be located in the files dir during installation of an app?

Tags: android, android-studio

My goal is to have `/data/data/pkgname/files/mydir/myfile.txt`

By default there are only `cache` and `code_cache`

I know that I can `getFilesDir()` in code and create necessary directories and files.

However is it possible to simply create necessary dirs with files in the project folder before building? (I tried creating this dir in root of the project, in main, src, nothing seems to work)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However is it possible to simply create necessary dirs with files in the project folder before building?

No, sorry.

You can put a directory tree with files in `assets/`. However, those do not turn into files on the filesystem of the device automatically. You can access them via `AssetManager`, either to just use directly or to serve as the basis for copying that tree to files in `getFilesDir()`.

Comment: I have an util compiled along with the app that requires a full path to a file. 
So, if I have assets folder with a video file, it means that I must copy it and thus have it twice?
What's the best practice here?

Comment: @Andrew: "it means that I must copy it and thus have it twice?" -- by default, yes. "What's the best practice here?" -- fix the utilty, if possible. If not, consider downloading the data from a server on first run of the app, rather than packaging it in the APK.